# Sharing state of selected button between components

Tags: angular

How do I have a Nav component share the selected section with a separate section detail component?

I am following the Angular 2 and I have gotten to the services part of the tutorial where you share data about each section with a service.

My issue is that I separated out the navigation like buttons from the main app component by moving it to a Nav component. The Nav and section detail components are both displayed with the app component but nothing displays.

I can post code on request. I am on my phone at the moment.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html If this doesn't solve your problem, please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Your prose description of your situation is hard to understand.

Comment: There are lots of reasons why this could happen, anything from the component not getting the data, the service not being instantiated properly, the template having some errors, or some condition where the service and component don't get change detection done properly. I'd start with some static data in the service first, get it displaying. Then start trying to get your dynamic data updated.